# preg_match between newlines and beginning or ending

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a number of lines in my value where I need to run preg_match between newlines, returns and beginning or end.

```
$text = "
ENG CHG NOTE
2A
LTR CHK
AH 2000
YE
NOTE 2
";
```

for example:

```
preg_match("/((?P<value>\\d+(.\\d+)*?)\s?(?P<unit>YE))/"
```

I want to make sure that preg_match is only looking for digits and YE in the above example. In this example 2000, which belongs to AH, would show a false value for YE.  How can I include \r\n and beginning or end, surrounding my current regex?

Comment: `"/((?P<value>\\d+(.\\d+)*\s*(?P<unit>YE))/"`

Comment: Do you want it to only match if the entire line matches?

Comment: Could you please specify the expected output? If you only want to match digits followed with `YE` on the same line, you need to replace `\s` with `\h`, [`'~((?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)*?)\h?(?P<unit>YE))~'`](https://regex101.com/r/oO1kJ6/1)

Comment: Are you looking for `<digits> YE` ? If so, use horizontal whitespace `\h*YE` instead of `\sYE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this example 2000, which belongs to `AH`, would show a false value for `YE`. How can I include `\r\n` and beginning or end, surrounding my current regex?

In the example you have, the number comes right after a `YE` followed with a newline. Since `\s` matches a newline symbol, too, you need to adjust the pattern to match only *horizontal spaces*.

There are two patterns you may leverage  here: `\h` or `[^\S\r\n]`.

```
'~(?P<value>\d+(?:.\d+)*?)\h?(?P<unit>YE)~'
                          ^^
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO1kJ6/2). [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/boS5Cv):

```
$re = '~(?P<value>\d+(?:.\d+)*?)\h?(?P<unit>YE)~'; 
$str = "ENG CHG NOTE\n2A\nLTR CHK\nAH 2000\nYE\nNOTE 2\n3444 YE\n"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```